# Parsing Date and Time from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

I created a component. It needs to return current date and time.

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date()
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (this.date);
    }
}
```

I need to access this data in component Home and set its time state with the returned value from home.

If my home component is like below,

```
export class Home extends Component {
    displayName = Home.name

    state = {
        time: null
    };

    handleTime = (timeValue) =>
        this.setState(currentState => ({
            time: timeValue

        }));        

    render() {
        return (
            <div>                 
                <div>
                    <Clock time="handleTime"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What is the mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set the time on your Home component the moment the Clock component is constructed. Not sure this is what you want though.

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          date: new Date()
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.handleTime(this.state.date);
  }

  render() {
      return <View>{this.state.date.toString()}</View>;
  }
}
```

And your Home component wasn't referencing your handleTime function the proper way (was missing curly brackets and the 'this' keyword to access class members):

```
export class Home extends Component {
  displayName = Home.name

  state = {
      time: null
  };

  handleTime = (timeValue) =>
      this.setState(currentState => ({
          time: timeValue
      })
  );        

  render() {
      return (
          <div>                 
              <div>
                <Clock time={this.handleTime} />
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. return ({this.date});  gives me an error

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be return ({this.state.date});

Comment: same syntax error. Saying like this is a reserved keyword

Comment: ./src/components/Clock.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/src/components/Clock.js: this is a reserved word (14:18)

Comment: I've made some changes to the main answer. I think now I got it right, please try again :)

Comment: thankyou. But still Im getting an error like, Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Oct 12 2018 05:57:06 GMT+0530 (Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Clock.js:15)
    in div (at Clock.js:15)
    in Clock (at Home.js:37)
    in div (at Home.js:36)
    in div (at Home.js:32)
    in Home (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:16)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:15)

Comment: Oh sorry, made one more change to the render on the Clock

Answer (score 1):

Edit your Home like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Clock from "./Clock";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: null
    };
  }
  displayName = Home.name;

  handleTime = timeValue => {
    this.setState({
      time: "timeTest"
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Clock time={this.state.time} />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleTime.bind(this)}>Change time</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And your Clock like this:

```
import React from "react";

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      time: props.time
    };
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.time);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.date.toString()}</div>
        <div>{this.props.time}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Clock;
```

Comment: HI Thanks. But getting an error like, Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Oct 12 2018 05:57:06 GMT+0530 (Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Clock.js:15)
    in div (at Clock.js:15)
    in Clock (at Home.js:37)
    in div (at Home.js:36)
    in div (at Home.js:32)
    in Home (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in App (at index.js:16)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:15)

Comment: Print state date: this.state.date.toString() not this.state.date

Comment: A little confused here, what do you want to do in handleTime,the time property want a string property,but you send a function to it.

Comment: @user3789200 I create a little example here for you. I assume that you want to change the time value with an event like click, then pass the value,not just pass a function to the time value.So I add a button to change the time value. https://codesandbox.io/s/1jn6mly3j

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the function `handleTime` to `Clock` component:

   ```
   <Clock time={this.handleTime} />
   ```
2. Use prop `time` at component `Clock` at constructor

   ```
   export default class Clock extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         date: new Date()
       }
       props.time(this.state.date); //U pass prop time
     }
     render() {
       return this.state.date.toString(); //return state string not object
     }
   }
   ```